# Calculating Binary equivalent in linked list using single traversal?

Tags: c, linked-list

The data in each node of a linked list contains either 1/0 with single traversal have to calculate the decimal equivalent

Using recursive and non recursive preferably C?

```
NODE *decimalData(NODE *head)
{
  int sum=0;
  if(head->next==0)
   {
             if(head->data==0) return 0;
                else return 1;
     }
   sum=decimalData(head->next);
   return 2*sum;
}
```

Comment: Function return type is Node and you are returning integer.

Comment: Check your compiler warnings, it should be complaining about the pointer to integer conversion on `sum=decimalData(head->next);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't say whether the data bit found at `head->next` is more significant than the current `head->data` or less significant.  If it's more significant, than the problem is somewhat simplified:

```
unsigned decimalData(NODE *head)
{
    unsigned sum = head->data;

    if (head->next != NULL)
    {
             sum += (decimalData(head->next) << 1);
    }

    return sum;
}
```